# Some Jquery/Javascript causing hover issues in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, hover

**UPDATED**

**I'm having issues implementing some Jquery that I'm using. At first I thought it was a cursor trail animation script I was using but now realised it's one used for a title marquee effect (I know it's not the best idea to use one but my client is set on having it)***

It seems to work fine in Chrome but in Safari it causes some hover issues on links. The cursor will flicker and not stay as a pointer when hovering any linked text or images. In safari, the pointer only seems to show on hover when moving the cursor.

Hoping someone might be able to help show me where I might be going wrong. Thanks!

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
 <!-- 
 var space = " ";
 var speed = "200";
 var pos = 0;
 var msg = "PAGE TITLE PAGE TITLE PAGE TITLE ";
 function Scroll()
 {
 document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + space + msg.substring(0,pos);
 pos++;
 if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
 window.setTimeout("Scroll()", speed);
 }
 Scroll();
 -->
```

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle or Stack-Code-Snippet with your HTML, JS and CSS Code? With that we can help, understand and solve your problem faster.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jordyogi/4xcxd8zL/ would this be enough? Apologies new to using this and can't publicly disclose too much about the site yet . Thanks

Comment: First, your if-condition should be in your pseudo-function, otherwise it wouldn't work if $ isn't assigned.

I tried to reproduce your error, but for me it looks as if nothing is wrong. (Safari looks like Firefox on OSX El Capitan)

Comment: But I've an idea what could happen: The stars are images, mabe these are overlaying when you're over a link and so (because they're moving) the pointer begins to flickr. (changing between pointer on a link/on a image). The solution shpuld be to make the images unclickable with the following css command: "pointer-events: none;".

So please check out, this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/_Sascha_/m826bszd/2/

Comment: Thanks @Sascha , I couldn't figure out why your fiddle worked and my page didn't so I've just stripped out all my other javascript/Jquery from the page and it fixed the problem. I found it was another script causing the problem so edited my question. Thanks again for your help!